# Query to search intranet address book with Excel data

Tags: excel, search, intranet

I am trying to search for employees that may have left our company in our internal address book on our intranet so I could deauthorize their access from a certain platform. I have all our platform users in Excel (Column B).

Does anyone know how to automate the process of searching each person from Excel column in a search bar on our internal address book? If the person cannot be found, I know they have left the company.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is "a certain platform"? And what is your "intranet address book" or your "internal address book" based on? Can't you just use Active Directory to prevent  expired users from logging on? "if the person cannot be found I know they have left the company" -- that looks a bit backwards to me. If they leave the company, you take steps to curb their access. If you don't know who has left your company or who is still an active user, searching you systems for failed matches looks like a very wrong approach. You need to tackle the problem at the root: Active Directory has tools for that.

Comment: "A certain platform" is an external reporting tool created for users and access is done manually on DB level and report level based on their LBU security (it's a global company). The internal address book is solely controlled by HR in each specific LBU when a user leaves which is then consolidated for the whole company. I have to manually search (approx 2000 employees) to cross check with the HR system.

Comment: If you don't name the products you use in your solution, it will be so much harder to help you. And what is "LBU"? Don't assume that everybody is familiar with your acronyms.  If you use a specific product to do a specific thing and you want to make changes to your process, then you need to name your product for people to be able to suggest what approach you could take. If push comes to shove, just use Excel Power Query to consolidate the systems.  Without more details it will be hard to give detailed advice.

Comment: Apologies - DB is database. LBU is Local Business Unit. Basically, I want to copy a cell in Excel (text) and search for it in a webpage. If no results found, I want that data in a separate column.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide all the details in your question. You may want to take the [tour] and learn [ask] if you expect meaningful answers from this site.